# Simulating correlated reaction times and accuracies in R

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, correlation

I would like to simulate reaction times and accuracies with a certain correlation among them.

This is my first guess:

```
n <- 2000

RTs <- brms::rshifted_lnorm(n, meanlog = log(1.3), sdlog = 0.1, shift = 0.5)

acc <- sapply(RTs,
              FUN = function(x){
                rbinom(
                  n = 1,
                  # multiplying by 0.3 should give me a correlation around 0.3... am I right?
                  prob = boot::inv.logit(x * 0.3), 
                  size = 1
                  )
                }
              )

cor(RTs, acc)
```

However, the resulting correlation is around 0 instead of being around 0.3.

What am I doing wrong?

I have seen this answer: [Simulation of correlated categorical and continuous data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66306304/simulation-of-correlated-categorical-and-continuous-data)
but it simulates categorical (that can be converted into binomial data) and gaussian distributions.

Comment: Since R is vectorized, you can do `acc <- rbinom(n, 1, plogis(RTs))` instead of using the `sapply`. It's not clear why you think the correlation should be 0.3. The inverse logistic conversion is giving you probabilities in a tight band between 0.6 and 0.66, so it will be difficult to see a signal over the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution for simulation by preserving correlation. All we need to do is to generate the binary variable (`acc`) in a controlled way (given the `RT` values generated).

Since the generated variable values need to maintain a fixed correlation, they both may not be drawn as independent samples from corresponding distributions.

The correlation between two random vectors can be increased if more and more high values in one variable correspond to high values of the other one and similarly the low values.

The following function `gen.correlated.binary.data()` starts with low numbers of ones in the target vector `acc` to be generated and gradually increases the number of ones corresponding to the high values of the variable `RT` (ensured by sorting).

This keeps the `RT` vector unchanged but gradually increases the correlation between the variables. Now stop as soon as the desired correlation value is reached - this creates the desired ordering of the pairs and proportion of ones in the `acc` vector.

Finally, the vectors are shuffled by preserving the correspondences (thereby keping the correlation constant), to generate the random `acc` vector.

```
gen.correlated.binary.data <- function(x, r) {
  n <- length(x)
  xs <- sort(x)
  ys <- c(rep(0, n-1), 1)
  rc <- cor(xs, ys)
  i <- n
  while ((rc < r) & (i > 1)) { # match sorted x with sorted y
    ys[i] <- 1
    i <- i - 1
    rc <- cor(xs, ys)
  }
  ix <- sample(1:n, n, replace=FALSE) 
  x <- xs[ix] # shuffle
  y <- ys[ix] # shuffle
  
  return(list(x=x, y=y))
}
```

Now, start with the generated `RT` vector and generate the `acc` vector:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 2000
RTs <- brms::rshifted_lnorm(n, meanlog = log(1.3), sdlog = 0.1, shift = 0.5)
res <- gen.correlated.binary.data(RTs, 0.3)
RTs <- res$x
acc <- res$y

RTs
# [1] 1.804578 2.025394 1.750515 1.611236 1.791022 1.910226 1.714558 1.667378 1.658610
# ...
acc
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
# ...

cor(RTs, acc)  
# [1] 0.3035055
```

The next figure shows the distribution of the variable values generated along with the correlation and the fitted line with `stat_smooth`.

[image]
The next animation shows how the `acc` vector was modified to achieve the correlation (`0.5` this time, by gradually increasing the correlation), given the `RT` vector:

[image]

Note that the `RT` vector and hence the distribution of `RT` is fixed, only the `acc` distribution changes, so that the correlation increases.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment and the excellent answer.

However, I have tried a different approach, that consists of simulating a multivariate Gaussian and then transform it as follows:

```
m <- 2
n <- 2000

sigma1 <- matrix(c(1, 0.4,
              0.4, 1), 
            nrow=2)

z1 <- mvrnorm(n,mu=rep(0, m),
         Sigma=sigma1,
         empirical=FALSE)

RT_acc1 <-
  cbind(
    0.3 + exp(z1[,1]),
    ifelse( boot::inv.logit(z1[,2]) > 0.5, 1, 0)
  )

qgraph::cor_auto(RT_acc1)
```

In this way, the correlation is around 0.4